# Set price of product variation in woocommerce via amazon api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have amazon products as product variations in my woocommerce store. I'm trying to develop a plugin that automatically sets the variation price based on an API request.

Following [this post](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/#comment-14035) I've added custom fields to the variations. One being the amazon ASIN:

```
<label><?php _e( 'Amazon ASIN', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
<input type="text" size="20" name="amazon_asin[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo $variation_data['_amazon_asin'][0]; ?>"/>
```

What I want to do now is using the value from the ASIN field to get the price from amazon when I update the product. Since I have multiple variations with the same custom fields, I also need to check whether the amazon_asin textfield actually has a value. I'm thinking something like this:

```
add_action( 'update_post_meta', 'get_amazon_price', 10, 4 );

function get_amazon_price( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
global $product, $post;

if ( 'amazon_asin' == $meta_key ) {

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {

        if (get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_amazon_asin', true) != null) {

            $asin = get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_amazon_asin', true);

            $publicKey = 'XXXXX';
            $privateKey = 'XXXXX';

            $xml = aws_signed_Request('de',
            array(
              "AssociateTag"=>"XXX",
              "MerchantId"=>"Amazon",
              "Operation"=>"ItemLookup",
              "ItemId"=>$asin,
              "ResponseGroup"=>"Medium, Offers"),
             $publicKey,$privateKey);

            $item = $xml->Items->Item;

            $price = $item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->Amount;

            update_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_price', $price);
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, this is not working and it might be the wrong way to do this all together. I know (from a different script) that the aws_signed_Request is working alright. Meaning I do get the right $price if I enter the right $asin. For the rest: I'm completely lost to be honest.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thx
//Seb